# How to query in hibernate with alias Bean Class which has annotated fields?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In hibernate I am creating custom query like below.

```
Query query = getSession()
            .createSQLQuery(
                    "select t2.* from ( select (select id from ctc_ver_assets ti where ti.ctcassettag = t1.ctcassettag  order by ti.createddate desc limit 1) lid from "
                            + "( select distinct ctcassettag from ctc_ver_assets) t1) ro, ctc_ver_assets t2 where t2.id = ro.lid and date(createddate) ")
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(VerificationAsset.class));
```

My verificationAsset class contains field namely ctcAssetTag but the field name in table is ctcassettag. How can I map this to the object automatically?

I can rename the individual fields in the query itself like `t2.ctcassettag as ctcAssetTag`. But I do not want to do that for each field because I already annotated each field in my Bean class like below

```
@Column(name = "ctcassettag", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String ctcAssetTag;
```

When I use criteria it is working fine. How to achieve the same with query?

Comment: solution 1: you can use 'alias_to_entity_map' so you don't need to declare model name. it will map your result according to your query.
solution 2: you can create @transient fields in your model to map fields as you wanted.
solution3: you can create DTO and use it in aliasToBean(VerificationAssetDTO.class) instead of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

### solution 1:

you can use `alias_to_entity_map` so you don't need to declare model name. it will map your result according to your query.

### solution 2:

you can create `@transient` fields in your model to map fields as you wanted.

### solution3:

you can create DTO and use it in `aliasToBean(VerificationAssetDTO.class)` instead of your solution.